# VS Code Turn off wrapAttributes for auto formatter

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I have the following html codes:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Whenever I use VS code's auto formatter by pressing `shift+Alt+f", it just wraps the` integrity`attribute to the next line. I would like to keep everything on one line. I did some research, and found out the setting that control it is`html.format.wrapAttributes`, but according to the documentation, the only four settings are:

```
auto: Wrap when the line length is exceeded
force: Wrap all attributes, except first
force-aligned: Wrap all attributes, except first, and align attributes
force-expand-multiline: Wrap all attributes
```

There is no setting to turn it off. I have tried to set it up as `"html.format.wrapAttributes": false` and `"html.format.wrapAttributes": ""`. They do not help.

I am wondering how to setup VS code such that every time I use VS code HTML auto formatter, it does not wrap `integrity` attribute to another line anymore?

Comment: does "html.format.wrapAttributes": "aligned-multiple" work?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to choose `preserve` or `preserve-aligned`.

[image]